# Angular 4 - injected html disappears when changing html/ts

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a simple Angular 4 http get following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76nZ9q_BUn8
I have created a new project using `ng new weather`.
The app-component is properly injected into index.html, I just checked, it works, but when I edit app.component.ts, exactly: I add constructor to the export class, html of app component disappears from the page.
This is my app.component.ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: Http){
  };
  cityName='';
  searchCity(){
    this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=<here is my unique correct id>&q=' + this.cityName).map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
.subscribe(
    (data) => {
      const weatherCity = data
      console.log(weatherCity);
    });
      }
      title = 'app';
    }
```

This is html:

```
<h1>
  Weather App

  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]=cityName>
  <button (click)=searchCity()>Search</button>
</h1>
```

The injected html disappears either when I add constructor to .ts or when I add input or button like this to html.

Do you know how it happens and how to make it work?

EDIT: I noticed one more thing: when I remove http: Http from constructor it works, however with empty constructor and ngModel it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error it was due to i forgot to add

HttpCliendModule in app.module.ts file

```
    import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
```

and in imports array add

```
    imports:[HttpClientModule,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

and change the http request

```
 this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=<here is my unique correct id>&q=' + this.cityName).map((resp:Response) => resp.json())
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      const weatherCity = data
      console.log(weatherCity);
    });
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but still the same, html is not in the page, it comes back when I remove script.

Comment: you can put the html